# Use a watermark in a TextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This is my code:

```
@Html.TextBox("Email", new { placeholder = "Email", Title = "Email" })
```

It does not work - when I run it, the browser displays the text inside the TextBox, and the HTML content that is: `("placeholder = "Phone", Title = "Phone" ")`.

Comment: Please rephrase your question so you can get more attention. Which text do you want, is it **Phone** or **Email**? Or are you asking for two textboxes?

Comment: sorry for my poor english....i got the answer..answer is @Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { placeholder = "Email", title = "Email" }).

Comment: Don't tell me you got it working just now? Darin gave the correct answer and you accepted it like a week ago, ain't that right? In any case, cool you got it working.

Comment: actually i got the answer a week ago and also that answer was i accepted... when Darin replayed ,that answer is very help full me so  i go for that answer i forget to replayed your comment...sorry its my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload of the `TextBox` helper. The second argument is the value and the third argument are the html properties.

So, here's how to fix it:

```
@Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { placeholder = "Email", title = "Email" })
```

I think your confusion stems from the fact that the strongly typed `TextBoxFor` helper takes 2 arguments:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { placeholder = "Email", title = "Email" })
```

Comment: Darin, I think you intend to type `TextBoxFor`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I intended to write :-) Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. And I'm glad to help someone, even in a molecularly-tiny-bit, who has helped a legion of people in a galactic-size way :)